# $\max\{\chi(G):G$ embeds on projective plane$\}=6$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

My lecture notes in Discrete Mathematics state that
$$
\max\{\chi(G) \; : \; G \text{ embeds on projective plane} \}=6, 
$$
but I have no idea where this comes from. $\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number of $G$. How does such an emebedding looks like?

Comment: Do you know planar graphs? They are the ones that can be draw on an Euclidean plane, or "embeds in" the euclidean plane. The statement you quote is about graphs that can be drawn on the real projective plane (which includes all planar ones, and some additional ones such as $K_5$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete graph $K_6$ has chromatic number $6$ and embeds in the
projective plane.  A nice way to see the embedding is to start from
the regular icosahedron in the sphere $S$, which has six opposite pairs
of vertices.  For each pair $\pm P, \pm Q$, each of $\pm P$ is 
adjacent to $Q$ or $-Q$ but not both.  So the image of the icosahedron
in the projective plane $S / \{\pm1\}$ is an graph with six vertices,
each adjacent to the other five, i.e. an embedding of $K_6$.

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me a lot.